# Create multiple UICollectionViews with custom cells in one ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I want to add three `UICollectionViews` in one ViewController. I want that two of them have custom cells. There would be no problem if the `CollectionViews` had no custom cells.

That would be my solution for no custom cell:

```swift
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell: UICollectionViewCell?


        if collectionView == gamePad{
            cell = gamePad.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "coloredCell", for: indexPath)
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            cell?.layer.cornerRadius = (cell?.frame.height)!/2

        }
        if collectionView == blackCounterCV {
            cell = blackCounterCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "blackC", for: indexPath)
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            cell?.layer.cornerRadius = (cell?.frame.height)!/2    
        }
        if collectionView == whiteCounterCV {
            cell = whiteCounterCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "whiteC", for: indexPath)
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            cell?.layer.cornerRadius = (cell?.frame.height)!/2

        }
        return cell!
    }
```

I have a label, which I created in a separate file. Now I saw, that I have to cast the cell as the Class of the `UICollectionViewCell`.

That's my idea, which didn't work:

```swift
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell: UICollectionViewCell?


        if collectionView == gamePad{
            cell = gamePad.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "coloredCell", for: indexPath)
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            cell?.layer.cornerRadius = (cell?.frame.height)!/2

        }
        if collectionView == blackCounterCV {
            cell = blackCounterCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "blackC", for: indexPath) as! BlackCCollectionViewCell
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            cell?.layer.cornerRadius = (cell?.frame.height)!/2
            cell.blackLbl.text = "TEST"
        }
        if collectionView == whiteCounterCV {
            cell = whiteCounterCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "whiteC", for: indexPath) as! WhiteCCollectionViewCell
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            cell?.layer.cornerRadius = (cell?.frame.height)!/2
            cell.whiteLbl.text = "TEST"

        }
        return cell!
    }
```

The Error, which is shown:

> Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell?' has no member 'blackLbl'/ 'whiteLbl'

So I think, that the cast didn't work like I wanted to.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: "I have a label, which I created in a separate file. "  can you explain this more ?

Comment: @Tobi I made a file with subclass UIcollectionviewcell and than I connected the label of the collectionview with that file

Comment: so you don't have a label on the cell on IB ?

Comment: What's IB? XIB? If yes, no I did it with storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell?' has no member 'blackLbl'/
>   'whiteLbl'

Your code seems correct so far the problem could be something missing in the `InterfaceBuilder`.

Therefore this problem could be a missing `Class` name missing in the cell.

make sure you added a class custom type to the cell in the `IB`

for example `BlackCCollectionViewCell` on the storyboard make sure that the right cell has this class. 
[image: Here]

UPDATE: since this was a compilation Error, Try this code.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == gamePad{
        var cell: UICollectionViewCell?
        cell = gamePad.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "coloredCell", for: indexPath)
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        cell?.layer.cornerRadius = (cell?.frame.height)!/2
        return cell!
    }
    if collectionView == blackCounterCV {
       let cell = blackCounterCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "blackC", for: indexPath) as! BlackCCollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.frame.height)/2
        cell.blackLbl.text = "TEST"
        return cell
    }
    if collectionView == whiteCounterCV {
        let cell = whiteCounterCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "whiteC", for: indexPath) as! WhiteCCollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = (cell.frame.height)/2
        cell.whiteLbl.text = "TEST"
        return cell
    }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

Comment: I actually added the class to the cell, so that isn't the problem unfortunately

Comment: I think, that the problem could be something with the downcast

Comment: can you move the         return cell! inside each if and try again